# Why does my window.onload code cancel out my other javascript?

Tags: javascript, resize, window, onload, hta

My work has recently decided to frown upon the use of VB so I have been forced to convert all of my old code to Javascript (and only Javascript).. I have successfully remade all of it without a hitch except for this one piece that resizes my tool based off of the monitor height that my agents use:

```
              <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function resizePage() {
    if (screen.height>=900)
    {
    window.resizeTo(455,820);
    document.body.style.zoom="110%";
    }
    else
    {
    window.resizeTo(395,720)
    }
    }
    </script>
```

The funny thing is that the code works.. The annoying thing is that it cancels out all of my other javascript in my HTA and makes my buttons completely useless. If I get rid of this specific piece of code everything works perfectly, I do not understand how or why this is causing such an issue.

I have tried multiple different ways to try and get this to work but cannot seem to solve it. I have also tried using body.onload in the body tag but even that causes issues because it makes my HTA go completely blank.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you for the help everyone, all of your code works with the resizer but it does the same thing with canceling out my other javascript.. I figured out the answer but I am so confused as to how or why this works.. I don't think this will help anybody in the future but I will post it if anybody is interested in the outcome of this.

I got it to work by putting this is my main file:

```
<script language="VBScript">

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload= function(){
if (screen.height>=900)
{
document.body.style.zoom="110%";
}
}
</script>
```

and this in my external .js file:

```
if (screen.height>=900)
{
window.resizeTo(455,820);
}
else
{
window.resizeTo(395,720)
}
```

The thing that is completely stumping me is that if I remove my VB that does absolutely nothing it causes all of my Javascript to break again. This is blowing my mind and I think I am just going to have to deal with this annoying piece until I completely remake my HTA.

Once again, thanks for the help everyone!

Comment: Um, you don't have two of `window.onload` for different things in there, do you?

Comment: Put the resizing code (not the zoom, though) within the `head` before the `HTA` tag. That way your app opens already resized, users don't need to see the original window size at all.

Comment: Nope, this is the only window.onload function that I have. That is a good tip though Teemu, thank you.

Comment: In general, there's only one "scripting space" which is shared by both languages. They share also variables and the DOM, i.e. you can refer JS variables and functions in VBS and vice versa (they also can override each other). I'd suggest you to add `language="JavaScript"` attribute to JS script tags. If you have inline event handlers, use the corresponding pseudoprotocol, for example `onclick="javascript: ..."`, if the function is defined with JS. I hope this helps and wish you good luck with the task.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
if (screen.height>=900)
{
window.resizeTo(455,820);
document.body.style.zoom="110%";
}
else
{
window.resizeTo(395,720)
}
}
</script>
```

Or this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function resizePage() {
if (screen.height>=900)
{
window.resizeTo(455,820);
document.body.style.zoom="110%";
}
else
{
window.resizeTo(395,720)
}
}
window.onload = resizePage;
</script>
```

Your code assigns a named function object to the onload event. If I knew more about JavaScript, I might be able to explain why that doesn't work.

In my first example, an anonymous function is assigned to the onload event, and that works.  In the second example a a pointer to a named function is assigned to the onload event.  I am unable to explain why assigning a pointer and assigning the function itself aren't equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error when using onload. Try removing the function name after window.onload and do it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function() {
     if (screen.height>=900)
     {
       window.resizeTo(455,820);
       document.body.style.zoom="110%";
     }
     else
     {
       window.resizeTo(395,720)
     }
   }
</script>
```

Comment: I believe you are right, but I tried Anakin's code both ways and could not get the way he posted it to break other JS.  I'll be interested to see what he reports back.